# An instance of quotient Space $X/M$

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

Hi Guys i can't find a simple example (with analytic description i mean) that helps me to understand the meaning of quotient space.

I've understood the definition ($X$ normed linear space, $M$ closed subspace of $X$, for each $x,y \in X$ $xRy$ iff $x - y \in M$ we define $X/M$ as the set of all equivalence class is there any example of the form

$X/M = \left\{ x+M : x\in X \right\}$

i'm asking such thing because even if i've understood the definition i don't know how to apply to build an example of "quotient space".

Comment: Note that the form expected in the example you want, implies that $X/M \subset X$, which is not quite true since the elements of the quotient space are equivalence classes. However you can have that $X/M \simeq X$, for example the latest happens if $X=\ell^p$ and $M=\{ (x_n)_n : x_{2n}=0 \}$

Comment: Ok i understood what is my problem ... the set $X/M$ is not a subset of $X$ because it is a set of equivalence classes... but now my question is how to describe set of equivalance classes? I mean... i know how to specify the "condition" so as two element can be defined equivalent, but i still don't understand the formalism to specify "set of equivalance classes". Because the book i'm using present a simple example that basically is described by "words" and not with "formalism".

Answer (score 4):

I like the next one. Let $X=C[0,1]$ with the usual $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ norm and $M=\{ f \in C[0,1] : f(1/2)=0\}$. It is easy to see that $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

Can you now prove that $X/M \simeq \mathbb{C}$? Where $X/M$ is equipped with the quotient norm $(\|\cdot\|_{X/M})$ and $\mathbb C$ with the complex modulus norm $(|\cdot |)$.

**HINT** Prove that $\phi : X/M \to \mathbb C$ given by 
$$
\phi([f]):= f(1/2) 
$$
is an isometric isomorphism, that is that $\phi$ is a linear bijection and that $|\phi([f])|=\|[f]\|_{X/M}$

**Spoiler solution**

> Note that $X/M=\{[f]: f \in X\}$ where $[f]=\{g \in X : f-g \in M\}=\{ g \in X : g(1/2)=f(1/2)\}$. Since $$\phi([\lambda f+g])=\lambda f(1/2)+g(1/2)=\lambda\phi([f])+\phi([g]),$$ $\phi$ is a linear map. Lets now check that $\phi$ is onto, clearly $\phi(X/M)\subset \mathbb C$, now if $z\in \mathbb C$ and define $f_z:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ as $f_z(t):=z $ for all $t \in [0,1]$, clearly $f_z \in X$ and $\phi([f_z])=f_z(1/2)=z$, hence $\phi(X/M)\supset \mathbb C$ and therefore $\phi$ is onto. Finally, fix any $f \in X$, by quotient norm definition, $$ \| [f] \|_{X/M}=\inf\{ \|g\|_{\infty}: g \in [f]\}=\inf\{ \|g\|_{\infty}: g(1/2)=f(1/2)\} \geq |f(1/2)|=|\phi([f])|.$$ On the other hand, if $h(t):=f(1/2)$ then $\|h\|_{\infty} = |f(1/2)|=|\phi([f])|$ and thus $h \in [f]$, hence $$ \|[f]\|_{X/M}=\inf\{ \|g\|_{\infty}: g \in [f]\} \leq \|h\|_{\infty}=|\phi([f])|.$$ So indeed $|\phi([f])|=\|[f]\|_{X/M}$. This tells you that as normed spaces $X/M$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are exactly the same one, just with elements having different names, for instance the element $[f]\in X/M$ is fact the element $f(1/2)\in \mathbb{C}$, since they have the same norm they are essentially the same one, and that is why we say that $$(X/M, \|\cdot\|_{X/M}) \simeq (\mathbb C, |\cdot|)$$

Comment: Actually i can't... and i neither know why i'm struggleling... I don't know how to apply the definition in such case (because i can't figure out the description of $X/M$ i'm looking for)

Comment: It is possible to say that $\forall x,y \in X$ then $x R y \iff x(1/2) = y(1/2)$?

Comment: Yes it is possible to that! That's the idea since each equivalence class $[f]$ can be identified by the complex number $f(1/2) \in \mathbb{C}$, and any complex number $z$ can be identified with the constant function $f\equiv z$. Can you now see why $X/M \simeq \mathbb C$?, it will only rest to veryfy that the identification I mentioned above is really an isometric isomorphism. @Lukkio

Comment: I try.. i let you know.

Comment: Just to be clear, prove that $\phi$ is an isometric isomorphism means that the norm of $[f]$ should be equal to the norm of $\phi([f])$ and that the it is also continuous with inverse continuous isn't?

Comment: That is correct. Since it is easily seen that $\phi$ Is a linear map, you only need to check that $\phi$ Is onto and that the norm of $\phi(f)$  is the norm of $[f]$. If you still struggling I can add a spoiler with a full solution, let me know! @Lukkio

Comment: Can you please give the solution?

Comment: I think i've understood your proof. And maybe the idea... A way to describe a set $X/M$ is to express it by means of an isomorphic set isn't? Is that correct?

Comment: @Lukkio That is correct. The space $X/M$ will not be expressed at first as a normed space you know, but in some cases, as in the example above, you can find a space you know and prove that as a $\color \red{\text{normed}}$ $\color \green{\text{space}}$ they are the same one, hence $\color \red{\text{isometrically}}$ $\color \green{\text{isomorphic. }}$

Comment: This is interesting... out of curiosity, if didn't want to use the isometric isomorphic map what would have been the best way to express the set structure? Is there a simple way? if it isn't such a way... is the isometric-isomorph maps the common way to express the set quotient set?

Comment: @Lukkio it is the comon and simpler way ! You can now try to do the other example I comment in your question, that $\ell^p/M\simeq \ell^p$, where $M=\{(x_n)_n \in \ell^p : x_{2n} =0 \forall n \in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try and i let you know! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi i haven't completed the proof yet (a bit busy) but i'm very curious if at least if i'm following the right way. In the same way as you done i defined a map $\phi \left( [ x_n ] \right) = x_{2n}$ which of course is $\phi( X\M ) \subset X$ for the inverse i've defined a function $f(x_{n}) = x_n$ (the identity map) so since using this i think i should be able to prove the converse inclusion (by applying $\phi( \dot))$. After this i suppose the isometry maybe it is easier than your case. Is that correct?

Comment: Hey there @Lukkio ! You are on the right track by putting $\phi([(x_n)])=(x_{2n})$. However, for the "inverse" part just note that if $(y_n) \in \ell^p$ then $(x_n)=(0, y_1, 0, y_2, \cdots )$ is such that $\phi([(x_n)])=(y_n)$ and hence $\phi$ is onto. Finally the isometry part is quite similar to the one on my answer, fixing $(a_n) \in \ell^p$ the first inequality ($\|[(a_n)]\|_{X/M}\geq \|\phi([a_n])\|_p$) follows almost analogously, for the second one use that if $(b_n)=(0, a_1, 0, a_2, \cdots)$ then $(b_n)\in[(a_n)]$ and conclude that $\|[(a_n)]\|_{X/M}\leq \|\phi([a_n])\|_p$

Answer (score 2):

**Quotient Space**

Given a Banach space $E$.

Construct the quotient:*
$$E/M:=\{x+M:x\in E\}$$

As well as its norm:
$$\|x+M\|:=\inf_{m\in M}\|x+m\|$$

By closedness indeed:*
$$\|x+M\|=0\iff x+M=0+M$$

**Here closed subspace required!*

**Example**

Given a measure space $\Omega$.

Consider the Banach algebra:
$$\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega):=\{f\in\mathcal{B}(\Omega):\|f\|_\infty<\infty\}=:\mathcal{B}$$

Regard the closed ideal:
$$\mathcal{I}_\mu(\Omega):=\{i\in\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega):i=0\bmod\mu\}=:\mathcal{I}$$

Construct the quotient:
$$\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega)/\mathcal{I}_\mu(\Omega):=\{f+\mathcal{I}:f\in\mathcal{B}\}=:\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{I}$$

As well as its norm:*
$$\|f+\mathcal{I}\|:=\inf_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\|f+i\|_\infty=:\mathrm{ess}-\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}\|f(\omega)\|$$

**This is essential supremum!*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perhaps easier to understand example. Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space. We say that a function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is an $L^1$ function, or $f\in L^1$, if
$$\int_X |f|\mathsf d\mu <\infty. $$
Now, strictly speaking, this is an abuse of notation. To be more concrete, suppose $X=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$. Then the function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x$ is $L^1$, since $$\int_{[0,1]} |f|\mathsf d\mu = \int_0^1 x\mathsf dx = \frac12. $$
But changing the value of a function at countably many points does not affect its integral, since the Lebesgue measure of a countable set is zero. Hence the function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x,& x\ne\frac12\\ 1000,& x=\frac12\end{cases} $$
is $L^1$, since again 
$$\int_{[0,1]} |g|\mathsf d\mu = \frac12. $$
From a measure-theoretic standpoint, $f$ and $g$ are essentially the same function; we have $f=g$ a.e. (almost everywhere) since $$\mu(\{x\in[0,1] : f(x)\ne g(x)\}) = 0. $$ So the actual definition of $L^1(\mu)$ here is
$$\left\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R \mid \int_X |f|\mathsf d\mu <\infty \right\} / \sim $$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation
$$f\sim g\iff f=g \text{ a.e.} $$
In other words, the elements of $L^1(\mu)$ are not functions, but instead *equivalence relations* of functions.

Comment: I like this one too! And it is useful to say that actually $L^1/\sim $ is a normed space meanwhile $L^1$ is not. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197337/measure-spaces-s-t-mathcall1-l1) is related to your example.

Comment: Hmm, in my measure theory course we wrote $L^1$ to denote $L^1/\sim$, and this is how it's defined in Folland, which is a rather standard text. But in these notes: http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/lp_inequalities.pdf I see that $\mathcal L^1$ is used to denote the set of integrable functions, and $\mathbb L^1$ for $\mathcal L^1/\sim$. So I guess this is just one of those cases where notation varies.

Comment: yes indeed! As you say in measure theory we usually make no distinction with functions and the equivalent classes, that is why we say that the $L^p$ spaces are Banach ones, when in fact the $L^p/ \sim$ are the ones who really are.

Comment: This is actually a good example of application of that definition. So the describe a set of all equivalence relationship we need both to specify the set and the relationship?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

What makes the whole subject so difficult is that most of the time it is spoken in abstract terms like saying these are indeed equivalence classes. This may and most of the time does create more confusion. In fact, equivalence classes are much easier to handle than one might think of as soon as one demascates them as merely... ...sets.

[image: Quotient]

Now, first ask yourself how would you define their distance to zero.
Then explicitely write it out on a piece of paper.
And finally think about what the essential supremum must look like in special.

Comment: This is the actual example that i understand in the meaning but i don't understand how to write... is the one that my book present, but it doesn't give any description of the set of "parallel line".

Comment: @Lukkio: An affine hyperplane is given by $x+M:=\{x+m:m\in M\}$. Collecting these gives $E/M:=\{x+M:x\in E\}$. Don't worry about double counts: Remember for sets it is $\{a,a,a,b,c,\ldots\}=\{a,b,c,\ldots\}$. So for $x+M=x'+M$ one has $E/M=\{x+M,x'+M,y+M,z+M,\ldots\}=\{x+M,y+M,z+M,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Ok... let's say a more practical example... let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $M = \left\{ (x,y) \in X \;|\; x + y = 0 \right\}$ how to write the set $X/M$?

Comment: @Lukkio: Basically the same. Try it here as comment!

Comment: I don't understand why it is so uncomfortable to me... i would try to write something like
$X/M := \left\{x + M : x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \right\}$ where $M := \left\{ (x,y) \in X \;|\: x + y = 0 \right\}$

Comment: @Lukkio: Besides my drawing was not meant to picture parallel lines but affine hyperplanes in a schematical way.

Comment: @Lukkio: Yes that is right. Sometimes things that seem to simple won't help. There's a famous principle by polya saying that you should look for the easiest example you can't solve yet. Obviously the parallel lines example you already know. So try to look for a harder one! How about the one given by alonso? *(That was a good exercise for me too.)*